# Reporting Services keeps erasing my dataset parameters

Tags: web-services, reporting-services, parameters

I'm using a web service and every time I change something on the dataset, it erases all my parameters. 
The weird thing is, I can execute the web service call from the data tab and it prompts for all my parameters, but if I click to edit the data the list is empty or if I try to preview the report it blows up because parameters are missing.
Just wondering if anyone else has experienced this and if there is a way to prevent this behavior.
Here is a copy of the dataset, not that I think it matters. This has to be the most annoying bug (if its a bug) ever. I can't even execute the dataset from the designer without it erasing my parameter list. When you have about 10 parameters and you are making all kinds of changes to a new report, it becomes very tedious to be constantly re-typing the same list over and over. 
If anything, studio should at least be able to pre-populate with the parameters the service is asking for. *sigh* Wheres my stress ball...

```
<Query>
   <Method Namespace="http://www.example.com/" Name="TWRPerformanceSummary"/>
   <SoapAction>http://www.example.com/TWRPerformanceSummary</SoapAction>   
       <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">
            TWRPerformanceSummaryResponse/TWRPerformanceSummaryResult/diffgram/NewDataSet/table{StockPerc,RiskBudget,Custodian,ProductName,StartValue(decimal),EndValue(decimal),CostBasis(decimal)}
       </ElementPath>
</Query>
```

Comment: I've seen this happen too but unfortunately I have no idea what causes it :-(

Comment: I think I'm going to call Microsoft Support later today, hopefully they will be able to help me out, I'll post my results here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was coming from inside the web service. I pass a sessionID (its a GUID) as a string to the report, then from the report to the web service. Inside the web service I take that string and convert it back to a Guid and pass it to our SecurityTicket object.

That is where the issue was occurring. Apparently this call:

```
Guid passedGuid = new Guid(sessionID);
```

Is not liked by the reporting services dataset. A Microsoft Support Escalation Engineer is working with me to verify what exactly is happening and if there is a fix, going to be a fix, etc... I am going to put a work around in place for my code, which does not require a GUID to be passed to out SecurityTicket.

**Edit - Solution**

Essentially, every time you make a change on the data tab, it fires off a call to the web service dataset sending null parameters. If you're web service can't handle null parameters it will error out erasing all your parameters. 
In order to easily overcome this, the first line in our web service checks for null parameters and sets some defaults. Then if the dataset being returned is empty, we add a dummy row:

```
private static void addDummyRow(DataTable dt) {
        var row = dt.NewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) {
            if (dt.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(string)) {
                row[i] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            }
            else if (dt.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(DateTime)) {
                row[i] = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
            }
            else {
                row[i] = 0;
            }
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this, and it's pretty annoying.  If you are developing from VS, just click on the Refresh fields button, and it normally clears up the problem.  If the query STILL throws an error, your SQL most likely has a bug in it (at least in my experience if "refresh fields" doesn't work, I made some stupid syntax error like "SELECT Field1 Field2..." or something like that).  You could also click the "Run query" button.

Comment: No, there is no SQL. Its a web service. Microsoft and I think we may have it figured out, at least narrowed down, but I'll wait to post the final results, so I don't put incorrect information here.